# Get API URL for BulkConnection

Tags: api, webservices, bulk-api, custom-domain

Is there a "right" way to get the correct endpoint for establishing a BulkConnection (force-ws.jar)?

I'm calling an external app from a visualforce page (already authenticated, passing session & endpoint). I've tried using `System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().gethost()` and `Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()`. I'm having the following problems:

- From within a package, the package namespace causes it to fail
- In normal orgs (na##.salesforce.com) and orgs with custom domains (my-domain-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com), they end up with "c.na##." or "my-domain-dev-ed--c.", which causes it to fail
- In all scenarios, "visual.force.com" causes it to fail and it needs to be switched to "salesforce.com"

The Partner API works just fine with the URL exactly as SF provides it, no manipulation needed. Why doesn't it work for the Force.com Web Services Connector?? Is there a correct way to get the right domain format that will work for all scenarios?